# Access host port as localhost from docker

Tags: docker

I have two machines connected via SSH tunnelling such that `machine1:2222` can access `machine2:2222` as localhost. `machine2` runs the container `docker2` and exposes services on port `2222` to localhost only. I can access these from `machine1` on port `2222`.

I would like to be able to access `machine1:2222` from `docker1`, a container running on `machine1` as `localhost`. I can determine the gateway IP address from within `docker1`, however connections are rejected because they come from the IP address assigned to `docker1` rather than `localhost`.

So, what is the best way to access services on `machine2` from `docker1` on `machine1`? Solutions I've seen seem to involve modifying iptables on the host machine which doesn't seem all that portable.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the `--net` flag is for:

```
user@machine1:/ docker run --net="host" -ti docker1 /bin/bash

root@machine1:/ wget localhost:2222
>> (this will download whatever a request to machine2:2222 provides)
```